# Using core.logic to make a simple matching function

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, clojure-core.logic

Suppose we define a relation `matches` via the following table:

```
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|     | *A* | *B* | *C* | *D* |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| *A* |     | X   | X   |     |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| *B* | X   |     |     | X   |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| *C* | X   |     |     |     |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
| *D* |     | X   |     |     |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
```

By this, it is meant that (in pseduo-code)

```
(matches A) ;=> (B C)
(matches B) ;=> (A D)
(matches C) ;=> (C)
(matches D) ;=> (B)
```

In core.logic, I think I would know how to make individualized functions which could approximate the behavior of `matches`:

```
(defn matches-A
  (run* [q]
    (membero q [B C]))) ;=> (B C)
```

...and so forth for `matches-B` and `matches-C`.

**Question:** How could I generalize, i.e., `matches-A` to a single function `matches` as above?  In particular, I'd be interested in making it so that you could run queries like `(matches "not A")`, `(matches "B and C")` and `(matches "C or D")` (in pseudo-code) to get results like `(A D)`, `(A)`, and `(A B)` respectively. Is this possible?

NOTE: I'm using clojurescript instead of clojure. I'm not sure if that would impact the answer at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `conde` to solve this task:

```
(ns qradv.welcome
  (:require [cljs.core.logic :as l]))

;; |-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
;; |     | *A* | *B* | *C* | *D* |
;; |-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
;; | *A* |     | X   | X   |     |
;; |-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
;; | *B* | X   |     |     | X   |
;; |-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
;; | *C* | X   |     |     |     |
;; |-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
;; | *D* |     | X   |     |     |
;; |-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
(defn matches [x]
  (l/run* [y]
    (l/conde
      [(l/== x "A") (l/membero y ["B" "C"])]
      [(l/== x "B") (l/membero y ["A" "D"])]
      [(l/== x "C") (l/membero y ["C"])]
      [(l/== x "D") (l/membero y ["B"])])))

(prn (matches "A"))
(prn (matches "B"))
(prn (matches "C"))
(prn (matches "D"))
```

Output:

```
("B" "C")
("A" "D")
("C")
("B")
```

Comment: Is there a way to embed logical arguments into this function (like "A and B" or "not C" and so forth)?

Comment: @George I am not sure how you want to use 'not C'. Can you add example to describe the table?

Comment: Good point -- that has ambiguous meaning. By -- i.e. -- "not C" I mean "(B C D)". That is, I mean the complement of what is matched by C (as opposed to the aggregate of what matches the complement of C).